# Under what condition does $f(x)>0 x-a.e.$ iff $f(X)>0 \omega-a.s.$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Given measurable function $f$ and random variable $X$, it is true that $f(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{S}_X$ iff $f(X)>0$ where $\mathbb{S}_X$ denotes the support of $X$. Is this proposition still true for the $a.s.$ circumstance? i.e.

Is it correct that $f(x)>0 \quad x-a.e.$ on $\mathbb{S}_X \Leftrightarrow f(X)>0 \quad \omega-a.s.$?

It seems to be an evident proposition but I don't know either how to prove it or what condition should $X$ satisfy. I think the above proposition is true when $X$ is absolutely continuous or discrete.

I appreciate it if you could show me the detailed proof or provide me with references.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a condition for it to be true, but this should not always necessarily be true (for example when $X$ is discrete like you stated). For example, take the function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that is $0$ on a finite set of given points $\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$, and $1$ everywhere else. Then it is true that $f(x) > 0$ $\ x$-a.e., but we could for instance define a random variable $X$ which takes on only the values $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ each with probability $1/n$. Then $f(X)$ will always be $0$.

Comment: Thanks for your help! In your example, $f(x)=0$ on the support of $X$ is indeed true, i.e. $f(x)>0$ a.s. on $\mathbb{S}_X$ is not satisfied.